# SQL Syntax Error 42X01

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a website with a backend database. However, when I am trying to input the commands to create the tables, I keep on getting an error that I don't understand. I tried the commands on another platform (mySQL oracle online) and there's no problem. How can I find this?

**Command**

```
CREATE TABLE Team
(
Team_id INT (1),

Team_name VARCHAR (20),

Region VARCHAR (10),

League VARCHAR (30),

Manager VARCHAR (20),

CONSTRAINT PK_Team PRIMARY KEY (Team_id)
);
```

**Error**

> Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "(" at line
>   2, column 14. Line 1, column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Team
(
Team_id INT,

Team_name VARCHAR (20),

Region VARCHAR (10),

League VARCHAR (30),

Manager VARCHAR (20),

CONSTRAINT PK_Team PRIMARY KEY (Team_id)
);
```

Comment: Ok. That has worked. But when I try that with another commandm I'm getting the same error. I spaced everything out. It is very similar to the first command. How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe you are using everywhere INT (1) as datatype, instead of INT. If you declare column data type as integer, you only need to use INT, without additional parameters (like when you declare VARCHAR).